# Implement JSR135 for JVM using on linux arm device

Tags: java-me, mmapi

I'm porting a JVM to my linux arm set-top box. I've already built the [phoneME](http://java.net/projects/phoneme) Advance successfully for it and can run a midlet game well. But it couldn't play sound, so I think maybe JSR135 is needed.

1. Does anyone have the experience on how to implement and port the JSR135 to a phoneME ?
2. Is it possible to play sound without the JSR135 ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to play sound without the JSR135 ?

It is possible eg with [MIDP media package](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/media/package-frame.html) that includes subset of [JSR 135](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/mm/jsr135/index.html) (also known as ABB, Audio Building Block) - if the playback features stay within bounds of specified subset.